# Getting "Server Error" when click on "New Account" in gerrit

Tags: mysql, gerrit

I am getting `server error` when i am try to register `new user` at first time. It works fine if i configure with `H2` database.

My `gerrit.config` file is :

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://localhost:8081
 [database]
    type = mysql
    database = reviewdb
    hostname = localhost
    username = gerrit
[index]
    type = LUCENE
[auth]
    type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = gerrit
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:8081/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

Comment: Also getting following error when i run `java -jar gerrit*.war init` : `Cannot update refs/meta/config in /opt/gerrit/git/All-Projects.git: LOCK_FAILURE`. I checked `git` directory permission which looks fine. Directory permission is `drwxrwxr-x 4 gerrit gerrit     4096 Mar  9 11:06 git`

Comment: Anything interesting in the Gerrit log file?

Comment: As which user do you use to run the `java -jar gerrit*.war init` command? What does `id` say?

Comment: I am doing it on `gerrit` user. I was able to run successfully in new directory, i mean i specified `java -jar gerrit*.war init -d <directory path>`. Thnx to all.